# Which log file can I empty?

Tags: linux, redhat, log-files

The munin log and chkservd.log becomes quite large. Is it safe to empty them using cat /dev/null > xxx.log?

In general, is it safe to just empty any log file?

[image]

Comment: As EEAA's answer says, "it depends".  And one more suggestion to set up proper log rotation...

Comment: Be careful.  Some loggers hold the log file open and so the truncate doesn't actually free up space until the log is closed.

Comment: Truncating requires no cat! ```>/var/log/thing```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The munin logs should be fine to truncate, provided that you don't actually care about their contents. Going forward, consider installing logrotate, which can take care of log maintenance, compression, export, etc. automatically.

In regards to other logs, you'll need to evaluate each based on your own requirements. There are some logs, namely database transaction/binary logs, which are critical to operation of the database, and you may cause problems if you truncate those.

In summary: it depends.